# Maven properties loading order

Tags: java, maven

I know that Maven properties can be defined in different locations:

- `~/.m2/settings.xml` on the local machine
- `<properties>` in the project parent POM
- `<properties>` in the project child module POM
- `<properties>` in Maven profile of the project parent POM
- `<properties>` in Maven profile of the project child module POM
- `-D` directly on the command line

But it's not very clear in which order the properties are loaded. Could somebody explain its order?

Comment: The question is: Why is this important ?

Comment: This is important because a defined property value could be overwritten, by the same property defined in another place. Without knowing the exact order, the only solution to avoid such situation is to define a property in only one place. @khmarbaise

Comment: In addition, the same property might be defined in more than one profile in a POM.  If both profiles were activated, which would win?

Comment: Thanks for the question which leads to the answer. CI may define a var which overwrites my local pom.xml one and it should take precedence in the pipeline, meanwhile allowing me to change pom.xml in local builds.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Based on my tests, the precedence of properties seems to be the following, where 1. takes precedence over 2.; 2. takes precedence over 3. and so on.

1. `-D` property via command line
2. `<properties>` in `<profile>` in `settings.xml`
3. `<properties>` in `<profile>` in the child pom
4. `<properties>` directly in child pom
5. `<properties>` in `<profile>` in the parent pom
6. `<properties>` directly in parent pom

So generally:

- Commandline before everything
- Settings before child before parent
- profile before directly defined properties

I tested it with the following setup.

settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0                       https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <custom.prop>settings</custom.prop>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

parent pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <custom.prop>parent</custom.prop>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <custom.prop>parent-profile</custom.prop>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

child pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-child</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <custom.prop>child</custom.prop>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <custom.prop>child-profile</custom.prop>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo message="${custom.prop}" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Run it like this and delete the property which is `echo`ed, repeat as long as there is a property left.

Comment: In the case of a property being defined in more than one profile in the same pom - the value that wins, seems to be: the one in the last-defined profile in the file.

Comment: Here https://davidmarquis.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/maven-custom-properties-precedence/ is a very old list of precedences. At that time, the profiles were evaluated in alphabetical order. That may have changed.

Comment: Note also, in the list above, things higher on the page with lower item numbers have precendence over things lower on the page, further down the list with higher item numbers. I know, its a personal problem, not knowing which order the list is in.

Comment: which one of this is considered as System Properties?

Comment: @Eduardo properties given via `-Dproperty=value` on the command line are Java System Properties