# Can I use formatter-maven-plugin to format a single file in project?

Tags: java, maven

I wondering if it possible to format a single file from project using **mvn formatter** in command line? Something like this:

```
mvn formatter:format /projecet/helloWorld.java
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The documentation https://code.revelc.net/formatter-maven-plugin/format-mojo.html#includes says there is user property `formatter.includes`. So, try passing it as usual `mvn -Dformatter.includes=someFilenamePattern ...`

Comment: Have tried it does not work in way I need. It includes a file to be formatted but still formats also whole project. The same time I need to the only one file to be formatted.

Comment: Indeed it works, was my fault that I missed that in my pom I had 
<includes>**/src/main/java/**/*.java</includes> which is higher on priority than -Dformatter.includes

Comment: @dreddred that's weird. Are you sure? I thought command line properties are the highest priority: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49598655/maven-properties-loading-order